# php jquery straight url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, url

Hello, I have some questions about how to protect this script from a straight url?

Members can just can go 'pages/map/hospital.php?status=healed' and voila, they don't need any wait time.  How do I fix this?!

```
<?php
$status = $_GET['status'];

if(isset($status)){
 session_start();
 include('../../includes/core/member.php');
 include('../../includes/core/config.php');
 $member_id = $_SESSION['member_id'];
  if($status == 'healed'){
   mysql_query("UPDATE `members` SET `now_health` = '".$m_max_health."' WHERE `member_id` = '".$member_id."'");
  }

}else{
 include('includes/core/member.php');
}

$health = $m_max_health - $m_now_health;
$wait_time = $health * 5;
?>

<p id='health'>Healing (<?=$wait_time?>)</p>

<script>
$('#health').one('click', function() {
  var count = <?=$wait_time?>;
  countdown = setInterval(function(){
    $("p#health").html(count + " seconds remaining!");
    if (count == 0) {
      $.ajax({
       url: 'pages/map/hospital.php?status=healed',
       success: function(data) {
        clearInterval(countdown);
        $("p#health").html('you have healed');
       }
      });
    }
    count--;
  }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but shouldn't `session_start();` ALWAYS be first in the code?

Comment: @max: no. it only has to be placed before anything that produces output and/or needs to use a session variable.

Comment: i replace't ajax with post , all work's fine for me , thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Server-side validation is required.

I see that you already have the initial $wait_time in a variable.  So you would want to leverage this and perform some basic math using a datetime function to ensure the count <= 0.

Comment: i have some other idea

    if($_POST['heal']){
     //make mysql udpate
    }

i need jquery code which make post , sorry i don't know jquery language.